# Google Analytics API - fetch back page views for many pages

Tags: php, cakephp, google-analytics

I'm trying to write a custom API query in (Cake)PHP for Google Analytics that will fetch back the page views for the last 12 months for a group of (potentially many) pages.

Here's what I've got so far:

```
$metrics = "ga:pageviews";

$params = array(
    'dimensions'=>'ga:date',
    'filters'=>'ga:pagePath==/enquires/add/200,ga:pagePath==/enquires/add/201',
    'sort'=>'ga:date',
    'max-results'=>366
);

$startDate = date('Y-m-d', time()-60*60*24*365);
$endDate = date('Y-m-d', time());

$data = $this->service->data_ga->get('ga:' . $profileId, $startDate, $endDate, $metrics, $params);
```

...which works for a couple of pagePath filters, but unfortunately the filter param which I'm using to filter just the pages I want is limited to a maximum of 128 characters.

If I have many urls I want to use in my report (say 50, but could be more) how do I get google analytics to filter them?

I've tried coming up with a regex but that's still too long.

I've thought about asking for *every* page ( or the regex /enquires/add/* ) and then filtering out the ones I'm looking for but that feels like the wrong way of doing things.

How can I pass a long list of filters to Google Analytics API? Or is there another way?

(BTW, this is for a property website and these reports are for property owners to see how often then properties have been viewed so it needs to be limited to only their property page urls)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not too much into the Google Analytics API, but this would be my approach to your issue if that API doesn't work:

- If the number of property owners is "limited", the easiest solution would be to add them as users to the Google Analytics assets they should have access to - no programming required at all.
- Maybe you should reconsider the way your Google Analytics assets are laid out. You could for instance create a unique tracking code for each property owner, effectively getting rid of the filtering at all.

If these approaches don't work for you, I'd just pull in all the available data, store them locally in the format that works best for the output to be generated, and then filter that local dataset. Depending on how complex you want to make it, you could have a look at ETL tools to ease the import & preprocessing / filtering.